# How to calculate average count of items on powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of product from a client. I need to calculate the average total price of products as well as the average count of products
I used this dax expression for an average total

```
Average Total of Price = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(wedding_data[Price]))
```

Here is the sample of the table:

```
    [Buyer], John,Francis, Charles, John, Francis
    [Wedding Date], 6/1/2019, 1/2/2019, 9/1/2019, 6/1/2019, 7/7/2019
    [Location], AK, NY, CO,AK, TX
    [Product_Name],iPad, Jewel, Books, Jewel, Shoe
    [Price], $5, $7.5, $6.12, $10, $21
```

Using the DAX above, one will obtain the average total price.
Now I need to do the average count of product, with the right DAX,

However, I am not sure what expression to use for the average count for each product.

I am supposed to get a value that if I multiply by the number of items, I will give the total sum of item.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, can you please provide an example of the data set?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added a sample data set.

Comment: above statement does not represent average, it represent % of the product.. like 40% of the product are Jewel, 20% are ipad.. Not sure what do you mean by average count of each product..

Comment: I provided an answer with a measure, alternatively there can be a calculated column alternative, depends on your report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Measure:

```
 ProductPercentage =

 VAR ProductCount =
     CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( wedding_data ) )
 VAR TotalRows =
     CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( ALL ( wedding_data ) ) )
 RETURN
     ProductCount / TotalRows
```

You have to have the row context as product.
One column has to be your product name and the second the measure.

[image]

***ALTERNATIVLY***

You can use a calculated Column to then summarize it in a table:

```
Column =
VAR productName = Table1[ProdName]
VAR ProductCount =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( Table1 ),
        FILTER ( Table1, Table1[ProdName] = productName )
    )
RETURN
    ProductCount
```

And then include it in a table using summarization type "Average":

[image]

And from here you can proceed performing any kind of operatins with the columnn or measure data.

*It all depends on your data structure and performance considerations.*

Answer (score -1):

Just right click on your fields pane **> New Measure** and add the following expression:

```
YourAverageMeasure = AVERAGE(Table1[Price])
```

The same goes for the count:

```
YourCountMeasure = Count(Table1[Price])
```

New depending on what you drag and dro into your table/chart (or filter) the measure gets calculated based on the data. Left table is Price and Name. Right table is just the average measure.

[image]

Comment: His problem was with the items where the name is counted more than once: a, a, b, c, c, ... , etc. And the percentage of those.

Comment: Oh yes, I wrote the wrong function.Just use `DISTINCTCOUNT()` instead of `Count()`

Comment: and what if 2 products have the same price and different names? You'd have to count the names not the prices. So your answer focuses on the wrong thing. You should probably take a closer look at what the guy wants to accomplish

Comment: Your scenario with 2 products have the same price is knowhere mentioned. This is a problem the op can and should now solve by his own with the given knowledge because this is not "solve my problem and provide code-forum" in the first place. And at a closer look on his questen there is now 100% right answer. Then tell me if you took a closer look a the question, how do you interpret the measure `average count of product`? Two aggretaes wont never work without more information.

Comment: _I am supposed to get a value that if I multiply by the number of items, I will give the total sum of item._ That is the line which interprets the line you mentioned

Comment: Which I answered with a toolbox to do even more depending on his scenarios. The key in Power-BI to chose the right chart - field combinations and leave the measures variable instead of calculate the measures fix